# Getting "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner at ReactJs.

And I have RangeError to run this code.

I have tried to solve this problem myself, but I couldn't do.

After a lot of testing, I just knew we had errors in this file.

Here is my code in the file.

```js
import React from 'react'
import cookie from 'react-cookie';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPieData, resetPieData } from '../actions/panel.js';
import PieChart from '../components/PieChart';
import { getCookieDomain } from '../utils/domain';
import PendingOverlay from '../components/PendingOverlay';
import cookiefetch from '../utils/userutils';
import {
  companyDropdown as companyDropdownAction,
  getCompaniesDropdown,
  getCompany
} from '../actions/companies.js';
import {
  getFileDropdown,
  fileDropdown as fileDropdownAction,
  fileSearchDropdown as fileSearchDropdownAction
} from '../actions/files.js';
const cookieDomain = getCookieDomain();
import {
  toggleExpiringModal
} from '../actions/ui.js';
import {
  checkdatediff
} from '../utils/numbers.js';
import '../assets/library.less'

class Panel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fileDropdownTitle: 'FILE',
      setFileByCookie: true
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    var roleCookie = cookie.load('role');
    roleCookie = roleCookie.toLowerCase();
    const accountId = cookiefetch('accountId','');
    var accid = accountId.toLowerCase();
    const overrideCompany = cookiefetch('overrideCompany', '');
    if(overrideCompany != '') {
      var title = "FILE ("+overrideCompany+")";
      this.setState({fileDropdownTitle: title});
    } else {
      this.setState({fileDropdownTitle: 'FILE'});
    }
    var roleCookie = roleCookie.toLowerCase();
    if (roleCookie == 'administrator' || roleCookie == "adminread") {

        dispatch(getCompaniesDropdown());

    } else {
      dispatch(getCompany(accid));
      dispatch(getFileDropdown(accid));
      //dispatch(companyDropdownAction(false, accid, accid));
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    const { selectedCompany } = this.props.companies;
    const { selectedValue } = this.props.companies.companyDropdown;
    const nextSelectedValue = nextProps.companies.companyDropdown.selectedValue;
    const nextSelectedDisplay = nextProps.companies.companyDropdown.selectedDisplay;
    const fileDropdown = this.props.files.fileDropdown;
    const nextFileDropdown = nextProps.files.fileDropdown;
    const cookieDomain = getCookieDomain();

    if (selectedValue == "" && selectedValue != nextSelectedValue) {
      cookie.save('selectedCompany', {selectedDisplay: nextSelectedDisplay, selectedValue:  nextSelectedValue, Petstore: nextProps.companies.selectedCompany.activePetstore2}, {domain: cookieDomain});
      cookie.save('selectedFile', {selectedDisplay: "Select a FILE", selectedValue:  ""}, {domain: cookieDomain});
      dispatch(getFileDropdown(nextSelectedValue));
      dispatch(fileSearchDropdownAction(false, "Select a FILE", "", ""))
    } else if(typeof nextSelectedValue == 'string' && selectedValue != nextSelectedValue) {
      cookie.save('selectedCompany', {selectedDisplay: nextSelectedDisplay, selectedValue:  nextSelectedValue, Petstore: nextProps.companies.selectedCompany.activePetstore2}, {domain: cookieDomain});
      cookie.save('selectedFile', {selectedDisplay: "Select a FILE", selectedValue:  ""}, {domain: cookieDomain});
      //dispatch(resetPieData());
      dispatch(getFileDropdown(nextSelectedValue));
      dispatch(fileDropdownAction(false, "Select a FILE", "", ""))
    }
    else if(nextState.setFileByCookie && typeof nextProps.companies.selectedCompany != 'undefined') {
      var nextCompany = nextProps.companies.selectedCompany;
      var companyOptions = {isActivePetstore: nextCompany.activePetstore, activePetstore2: nextCompany.activePetstore2,
        isActiveGeneral: true, isActivePoc: nextCompany.activePoc, isActiveFormat: nextCompany.activeFormat,
        isActiveSiteId: nextCompany.activeSiteId,
        subAssembly: nextCompany.subAssembly};
      if (nextFileDropdown.selectedDisplay == "List") {
        dispatch(fetchPieData(nextFileDropdown.selectedValue, true, companyOptions));
      } else if (nextFileDropdown.selectedValue != ""){
        dispatch(fetchPieData(nextFileDropdown.selectedValue, false, companyOptions));
      }

    }
    else if (nextFileDropdown.selectedValue != "" && fileDropdown.selectedValue != nextFileDropdown.selectedValue ) {
      cookie.save('selectedFile', {selectedDisplay: nextFileDropdown.selectedDisplay, selectedValue: nextFileDropdown.selectedValue}, {domain: cookieDomain});
      var companyOptions = {isActiveGeneral: true,isActivePetstore: selectedCompany.activePetstore, activePetstore2: selectedCompany.activePetstore,
        isActiveGeneral: selectedCompany.activeGeneral, isActivePoc: selectedCompany.activePoc, isActiveFormat: selectedCompany.activeFormat,
        isActiveSiteId: selectedCompany.activeSiteId,
        subAssembly: selectedCompany.subAssembly};
      if (nextFileDropdown.selectedDisplay == "List") {
        dispatch(fetchPieData(nextFileDropdown.selectedValue, true, companyOptions));
      } else {
        dispatch(fetchPieData(nextFileDropdown.selectedValue, false, companyOptions));
      }
    }
  }
  toggleExpiringModal() {
    const { dispatch, ui } = this.props;
    if (ui.toggleExpiringModal) {
        dispatch(toggleExpiringModal(false));
        cookie.remove('didLogin', {domain: getCookieDomain()});
    }
  }

  render () {
    var companyDropdownComponent = null;
    var filesDropdownComponent = null;
    var dataType;
    var expirationModal = null;
    var expirationDate, daysAway, didLogin;
    const { ui, companies } = this.props;
    const customStyles = {
      content : {
        top                   : '40%',
        left                  : '50%',
        right                 : 'auto',
        bottom                : 'auto',
        transform             : 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
        overflowY             : 'hidden',
        padding               : '20px 20px 30px'
      }
    };

    const isActivePetstore = cookiefetch('isActivePetstore', false);
    const roleCookie = cookiefetch('role');
    var role = roleCookie.toLowerCase();
    const accountId = cookiefetch('accountId', '');
    var accid = accountId.toLowerCase();
    const overrideCompany = cookiefetch('overrideCompany','');
    const { companiesDropdownData, companyDropdown, selectedCompany } = this.props.companies;
    const { fileDropdown, filesDropdownData } = this.props.files;

    const { pieData } = this.props.panel;
    const { table } = this.props.data;
    var companyOptions = null;
    if (fileDropdown.selectedDisplay == "List") {
      dataType = "masterList";
    } else {
      dataType = "file";
    }
    if ((role == "administrator" || role == 'adminread') && overrideCompany == '') {
      companyDropdownComponent = (
        <Dropdown
          errorMessage='Please select a company'
          error={false}
          title="Company"
          open={companyDropdown.display}
          selectedDisplay={companyDropdown.selectedDisplay}
          selectedValue={companyDropdown.selectedValue}
          options={companiesDropdownData}
          disabled="edit"
          onClickAction={companyDropdownAction}
        />
      );
    }
    if (companyDropdown.selectedValue != "") {
      filesDropdownComponent = (
        <DropdownFiles
          errorMessage='Please select a FILE'
          error={false}
          title={this.state.fileDropdownTitle}
          open={fileDropdown.display}
          selectedDisplay={fileDropdown.selectedDisplay}
          selectedValue={fileDropdown.selectedValue}
          options={filesDropdownData}
          disabled="edit"
          onClickAction={fileDropdownAction}
        />
      );
    }
    if (typeof selectedCompany != 'undefined') {
      companyOptions = {isActivePetstore: selectedCompany.activePetstore, activePetstore2: selectedCompany.activePetstore,
        isActiveGeneral: true, isActivePoc: true, isActiveFormat: selectedCompany.activeFormat,
        isActiveSiteId: selectedCompany.activeSiteId,
        subAssembly: selectedCompany.subAssembly};
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < companies.companies.length; i++) {
      if (accountId === companies.companies[i].accountId) {
          var dateInMiliseconds = companies.companies[i].expirationDate;
        expirationDate = new Date(dateInMiliseconds);
        expirationDate = companies.companies[i].expirationDate;
      }
    }


    { expirationDate != undefined ?  daysAway = checkdatediff(expirationDate) : null }
    {expirationDate != undefined ? didLogin = cookie.load('didLogin') : null }
    if (daysAway < 1 && ui.toggleExpiringModal == true && didLogin) {
      expirationModal = (
        <Modal
          isOpen={ui.toggleExpiringModal}
          shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}
          style={customStyles}
          contentLabel="Modal"
        >
          <div className="custom-modal">
            <div className="header-center">Notice</div>
            <div className="content">
              <p>test</p>
              <p>test in <span id="days">{daysAway}</span> days.</p>
              <p>test.</p>
            </div>
            <div className="buttons">
              <div className="close" onClick={() => this.toggleExpiringModal()}>Ok</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div id="panel">
        { !isActivePetstore ? <Notification>test</Notification> : null }
        {companyDropdownComponent}
        {filesDropdownComponent}
        <IconLink to="/files" title="Link to Files" type="table"/>
        { pieData != "empty" && pieData != "pending" && fileDropdown.selectedValue != "" ? <PieChart data={pieData} dataType={dataType} table={table} companyOptions={companyOptions}/> : null }
        { pieData != "empty" && pieData == "pending" ? <PendingOverlay/> : null }
        {expirationModal}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function select(state) {
  return {
    companies: state.companies,
    files: state.files,
    createFile: state.createFile,
    masterList: state.masterList,
    panel: state.panel,
    data: state.data,
    ui: state.ui
  }
}

export default connect(select)(Panel);
```

After running we have above error.

Comment: Post full stack trace of the error

Comment: This almost always means you have a recursive or circular call. function A calls function B which calls function A, resulting in a never-ending loop.

Comment: In `componentDidUpdate` you always dispatch an action. In your reducer you can log that action and see what action is causing an infinite loop and post the code of that reducer.